Errors with my file reading and subdirectory reading program
I have made a program that is supposed to do these two things. When a file is selected by the user, it is supposed to read the file, 10 lines at once, as directed by the user, and stop when it reaches the end of the file. Meanwhile, for a subdirectory, it is supposed to perform a recursive search to determine all the files in the subdirectory that have been last edited within 24 hours. Here is the functions of code I have below:
function handle_file() {
    local file="$1"
    local x=10
    local y=0

    head -n "$x" "$file"
    while true
    do
            if [ "$file" $? -ne 0 ]
            then
                    echo "End of file reached."
                    break
            fi

            read -p "Do you want to read more lines? " choice
            if [ "$choice" != "yes" ]
            then
                    break
            else
                    x=$((x+10))
                    y=$((y+10))
                    head -n "$x" "$file" | tail -"$y"
            fi
    done
}

function handle_directory() {
    cd "$1"
    echo "Files modified in the last 24 hours:"
    ls -1 "$1" | sort -nr | head -1
}

But it gives me some errors when I try it. When I try it with a file that has less than 10 lines or when I continue, this happens:
Oh my word, this tune is annoying
Yes I know, it's really annoying
I can't get this song out of my head.
Make it stop, this tune is annoying
I gotta go to work in the morning
Now I'm gonna be hummin' it in my bed.
./31504085_4.sh: line 22: [: too many arguments
Do you want to read more lines?

It's supposed to say that the end of the file is reached, since it has only 6 lines.
And when I do a directory, this happens:
Files modified in the last 24 hours:
ls: cannot access 'badgers': No such file or directory

Even though I have made this subdirectory, as shown below:
sgl24@instance-20240602-161447:~/weebl$ ls
annoying.txt  bonjour.txt  kenya         potato.txt  tamale.txt
badgers       horse.txt    narwhals.txt  scampi.txt  waffles.txt

Can you find a way to fix this problem?

What is $name?  What's $1 in handle_directory?  Did you cd to the same place as the ls is listing?  ls -1r ./

What is [ "$name" $? -ne 0 ] supposed to do? It does not look sane.

I think it's supposed to say "file." Let me fix it.

Always paste your script into https://shellcheck.net, a syntax checker, or install shellcheck locally. Make using shellcheck part of your development process.

Do you have a #! line as the first line of your script? If not, you should have, because it declares the interpreter for running the script. For example, #!/bin/bash or #!/bin/sh

The error message says, "./31504085_4.sh: line 22: [: too many arguments" - what is line 22 in your code?

if [ "$file" $? -ne 0 ]

Add this line at the top of your script set -x. It switches on tracing mode, so you can see what each line is doing. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10107170.
